# Want to use $lookup data in $match function

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I am using $lookup to find the stores and then I want to use $store.timezone in $match, the issue is "$store.timezone" is considered as a string.

```
let transactionData = await Transaction.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "store",       // other table name
        localField: "storeId",   // name of Transaction table field
        foreignField: "_id", // name of Store table field
        as: "store"         // alias for Store table
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$store",
    },
    {
      $match: {
        transactionType: { $in : ["refund", "redo", "standard", "combine", "donation"] },
        startTime: {
          $gte: new Date(moment.tz(startDate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", "$store.timezone").toISOString()),
          $lt: new Date(moment.tz(endDate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", "$store.timezone").toISOString())
        },
      }
    },
    {
      $group : {
        _id: "$customers.customerId",
        total : { $sum : 1 },
        store: {
          $push: {
            id: "$store._id",
            name: "$store.timezone",
          }
        }
      }
    },
    { $sort: { total: -1 } },
    { $limit : 10 }
  ]);
```

Comment: it is not possible to process the internal field of documents in an external function.

Comment: Is there any other way to perform this, because I want to compare the timezone of the store in the transaction table with startTime attribute.

Comment: no i don't think it is possible in a query.